# Microsoft Translator Api in JSON format

Tags: node.js, microsoft-translator

How can I use `Microsoft.Translator.TranslateArray` method in `Node.js` to send and receive data in `JSON` format as `XML` not allow\u001b etc. unicode. I am sending `JSON` request but getting this error:

> "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'to' must be a valid language\u000d\u000aParameter >name: to : ID=5639.V2_Json.TranslateArray.12E99F9A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REST API` to translate array of texts

`POST http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/TranslateArray`

Check the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512422.aspx) for details

you can use [request](https://github.com/request/request) module to hit this API.

**Example:**

```
var request = require('request');

request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/TranslateArray',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer *********' //put accesstoken
    },
    json: data //put your JSON here
}, function(err, res, body) {});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i am getting this error now                        <html><body/><h1>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</h1><p>Message: The data contract type 'Microsoft.MT.MDistributor.V2.TranslateArrayRequest' cannot be deserialized because the required data members 'AppId, Texts, To' were not found.</p></html>
^

Comment: Have you used `accesstoken`  in `HEADER`?

Comment: headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + accessToken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
            }

Comment: Do you have your accesstoken?

Comment: Please read the docs. If you don't have access token then you have to mention `APPID` or ignore it if you have accesstoken

Comment: Yes I have accesstoken

Comment: Can you post here your request call with xxxx accesstoken?

Comment: You can put your code here in comment box with xxxx access token

Comment: @FarhanYaseen I think, there's some required `parameter` is being missed in your `json`.